# Venn diagrams as database model - is there something similar like MPTT?

Tags: sql, database, venn-diagram, mptt

I am wondering about how to save venn diagramms into a database. Well actually I dont need to implement the complete venn diagram logic, it's more like a tree with one child beeing child of many parents at the same time.

My first guess was, to use a n:m-self relation to the table with a small helping table.

But I am used building trees with nested sets (see MPTT - Modified Preorder Tree Traversal). This helps me a lot not to iterate the query through all the childs.

Is there something similar like MPTT or a way to extent MPTT to my problem, which could help me avoiding to iterate through all the childs?

Thank you for any remarks or comments in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a general ordering of the regions of a Venn diagram. You just need to express each region as a binary number. The number of bits is the number of sets, and each bit shows whether the region belongs to a given set. For instance, for four sets,

```
Id         Binary    Interpretation
=======    ======    ==============
0          0000      Does not belong to any set
1          0001      Only belongs to set 4
2          0010      Only belongs to set 3
3          0011      Belongs to sets 3 and 4, and not to set 1 or set 2
4          0100      Only belongs to set 2
...
14         1110      Belongs to sets 1, 2 and 3, and not to set 4
15         1111      Belongs to all four sets
```

With this strategy, once you have defined the region you can immediately retrieve its `Id`, no tree is necessary.